# FOUC when using @material-ui/core with NextJS/React

Tags: material-ui, next.js

My simple NextJS page looks like this (results can be viewed at https://www.schandillia.com/):

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
  p: {
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    color: 'red',
  },
};

class Index extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const title = 'Project Proost';
    const description = 'This is the description for the homepage';
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>{ title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} key="description" />
        </Head>
        <Layout>
          <p className={classes.p}>amit</p>
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
            Secondary
          </Button>
        </Layout>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Index);
```

I am importing a bunch of components off the `@material-ui/core` library to style my items. I also have a local style definition assigned to a `style` constant.

What seems to be happening here is that my style isn't getting rendered on the server which is why the files being served upon load are sans-style. And then the CSS gets rendered by the client-side code. As a result, there's a flash of unstyled content that lasts almost a second, long enough to be noticable.

Any way to fix this? The entire codebase is up for reference at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web.

Comment: If you watch your elements inspector as the app loads you can see it injecting the MUI style tags in the <head>. I would play around with the configuration of how MUI is using JSS. This is an interesting page of info from MUI docs, the specific section starts giving suggestions for tweaking this aspect of performance: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#html-comment

Comment: I know my styles are getting injected into the `<head> section. But my problem is this injection is only happening at the *client* and not the *server*. That's what's causing the FOUC. I need some way to ensure the style information is injected at the server before the page is pushed.

Comment: No, am building with NextJS from scratch.

Comment: If you won't be doing any different configuration for your production build and you created your app using the `react-create-app`, I would recommend using the react-create-app's `react-scripts build`. I invested quite some time configuring a webpack for this and then discovered that it already comes with a simple but useful build tool ootb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a similar problem when tried to make a production build of my app, that uses material-ui. I manage to solve by adding a [JSS Provider](https://cssinjs.org/) like this:

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <JssProvider>
      *the rest of your material-ui components*
    </JssProvider>
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do this with every single page? Or can I just wrap my `<Main />` and `<NextScript />` elements in `_document.jsx` with `<JssProvider />` once and forget about it in each individual page (Index.jsx, About.jsx, etc.)?

Comment: I have a lot of components loaded in only two major components, like you. So I use it only on these major ones. I think if all of your components are being referenced inside `<Main />` and in the `<NextScript />`, just on them and forget about the individual ones. At least this worked for me

Comment: Ok, I looked at your code now, in your case, you use them on the same `RootDocument` component. You could wrap the `<JSSProvider>` over the `<Html lang="en">` or even inside the `RootDocument`  component if there you are using more material-ui styled components

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js .

Basically, all you need to do is to sync server-side class names with client-side. The link above shows what you need to do to fix that issue.