# How to add CSS server side render for React Next app with Material-ui

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a simple React app built in Next.js which is running an express server:

```
app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/job/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/job'
    const queryParams = { id: req.params.id } 
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

I also have [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) for material style components and need to make sure the components get server side rendered.

I have tried following [this tutorial](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#server-rendering) but can't seem to adapt the code to work with the way the Express server is set up in Next.js

I believe I essentially need to add some sort of `JssProvider` that will run server side and client side so that both have access to the style sheet. Correct me if I am wrong?

Does anybody know how this can be achieved in Next?

If anybody has a link to an example Next.js app that is set up with SSR Material-ui, that would be a huge help too.

Thanks

Comment: @PedroVieira is right in suggesting JssProvider.  For more details, this [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs#how-to-use) shows you how to use NextJS + Material UI

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the same problem I helped to solve in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528172/fouc-when-using-material-ui-core-with-nextjs-react/55657362#55657362). He was using NextJS too. You could add a JssProvider like this:

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    <JssProvider>
      *the rest of your material-ui components*
    </JssProvider>
  }
}
```

Comment: In this question mentioned has his example with NextJS